# React Jest test fails after using await keyword

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, axios

On the left a test case is shown for a input field change. After the `await` keyword, there is no console.log and assertions are failing. Could anyone help me fix the test?

[image]

The mock functions are defined as following:

```
 const handleChangeFn = jest.fn();
  const onCityResolvedFn = jest.fn();

  const oneCity = [{ zipCode: 8852, name: 'Altendorf'}];

  mockedAxios.get.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({ data: oneCity }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    handleChangeFn.mockReset();
    onCityResolvedFn.mockReset();
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't see 'after' in console because onPostalCodeChange is an async function, and you use the synchronous test.

First of all, you should make your test asynchronous. Add 'async' before the test function:

```
it('should ....', async () => {...})
```

Then, add a little pause before testing how many times a function has been called. You can use a construction like this:

```
await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 100))
```

This construction mean 'sleep 100ms'

I suppose, you will see 'after' in console.

If the problem remains, write here all the code of you test

**P.S**
Writing an async function in React hooks isn't a good practice

Comment: You're right. With your solution, the test passes. Thanks a lot :)
Regarding async function: I wanted to avoid recreating the same function (onPostalCodeChange), which fetches data from an api, in a functional component, therefore I used useCallback hook. What is the good practice to solve this problem?

Comment: I'm glad I could help. About an async function in hooks: I was wrong. You mustn't use an async function with the hook 'useEffect', but it possible to use  async with 'useCallback'